# jQuery: Add class to filter item containing active term, accounting for pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I'm working on an events page in a WordPress site that uses a set of filters to query posts; the markup for the filters is as follows:

```
<div class="event-filter">
    <a href="/events">All Events</a>
    <a href="/events?event-type=conference">Conferences</a>
    <a href="/events?event-type=webinar">Webinars</a>
    <a href="/events?event-type=learning">Learning</a>
    <a href="/past-events/">Past Events</a>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery to add an `active` class to whichever filter is currently in use, the simple code for which is as follows:

```
$('.event-filter a').each(function() {
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine except in the case that the resulting posts are paginated, as the url changes to reflect the current page, i.e. `/events/page/2/?event-type=conference`. How can I modify my JS to add the `active` class to the current filter if the URL *contains* the respective `event-type` term but also accounts for "All Events", and thus appends the class to "All Events" when the other filters are not in use? A couple notes: the "Past Events" option just links to an archive page that is a separate template from the main, filterable "Events" page; also, these filters are not using Ajax, they're just altering the WordPress query by URL parameter. Thanks for any insight here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it you will have to do a two part check, I would try something like:

```
$('.event-filter a').each(function() {
    var currentHref = window.location.href.split('?'); // ['https://myexamplesite.com/events/page/2', 'event-type=conference']
    var thisHref = this.href.split('?'); // ['https://myexamplesite.com/events', 'event-type=conference']
    var currentHrefHasQuery = currentHref.length > 1 ? true : false; // true
    var thisHrefHasQuery = thisHref.length > 1 ? true : false; //true

    if (currentHrefHasQuery != thisHrefHasQuery) {
        return; // they don't match
    }

    if (currentHrefHasQuery && currentHref[1] == thisHref[1]) { // if they have a query and the query is the same, it's a match!
        $(this).addClass("active");
    } else if (!currentHrefHasQuery && currentHref[0].indexOf(thisHref[0]) > -1) { //check to see if the current href contains this' href
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

This could definitely be simplified, but hopefully this is fairly easy to read.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m0hf3sfL/

Comment: thank you for the assistance- while "All Events" is activating as expected, when clicking on individual filters, all three with event-types defined are getting the class at the same time; do you know what might be happening here?

Comment: My bad, fixed it! It was an issue with the `else if`statement.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks much! All is working now. Just for the sake of education, what exactly is going on in the lines for `currentHrefHasQuery` and `thisHrefHasQuery` in checking `length`? Thanks again.

Comment: Above, when I assign `currentHref` and `thisHref` I am getting the string value, then turning it into an array with as many objects in it as there are question marks (indicating a query). Then, I am using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check the length of the array, if it has a query, then the array with will have more than 1 item in it.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you for the extremely informative answer!